# JSON Result Set for OpenWeather API not Returning Values for Main Dictionary in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

I am creating an application that pulls weather information from OpenWeather's API using JSON. I have nested "IF" statements that I am using to build a string of the current weather. The goal is to build a string of "Current weather is (description) with a temperature of (temp) and a wind speed of (wind)." Unfortunately, the if statement to retrieve the "temp" value from the "main" dictionary is failing to the else statement which just results in "Current weather is (description)." Can anyone tell me if my code is doing something that would result in me not being able to assign the "temp" value from the "main" dictionary to

Here is my code:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                        print(jsonResult)
                        if let description = ((jsonResult["weather"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["description"] as? String {

                            print(description)
                            var weatherString = "Current weather is \(description)"
                            if let temp = ((jsonResult["main"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["temp"] as? String {

                                weatherString += " with a temperature of \(temp)°"
                                if let wind = ((jsonResult["wind"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["speed"] as? String {

                                    weatherString += " and a wind speed of \(wind)mph."

                                } else {

                                    weatherString += "."

                                }

                            } else {

                                weatherString += "."

                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {

                                self.weatherResult.text = weatherString

                            })

                        }
```

Here are the results I am getting from the OpenWeather API:

```
{
    base = stations;
    clouds =     {
        all = 75;
    };
    cod = 200;
    coord =     {
        lat = "37.78";
        lon = "-122.42";
    };
    dt = 1548179880;
    id = 5391959;
    main =     {
        humidity = 60;
        pressure = 1030;
        temp = "51.37";
        "temp_max" = "55.04";
        "temp_min" = "46.04";
    };
    name = "San Francisco";
    sys =     {
        country = US;
        id = 5817;
        message = "0.0042";
        sunrise = 1548170423;
        sunset = 1548206575;
        type = 1;
    };
    visibility = 16093;
    weather =     (
                {
            description = "broken clouds";
            icon = 04d;
            id = 803;
            main = Clouds;
        }
    );
    wind =     {
        deg = 10;
        speed = "6.93";
    };
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Decodable and Codable so you won't have that much nested if else statements.
Here is an example from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistakes in your code are that `weather` is an array (`[]`), but `main` and `wind` are not (`{}`). And `speed` and `temp` are `Double`, not `String`

Nevertheless `JSONSerialization` is too complicated, `Decodable` is simpler, better readable and much more efficient.

The `Openweathermap` API sends always consistent data.

```
struct WeatherData : Decodable {  
    let weather : [Weather]
    let main : Main
    let wind : Wind
}

struct Main : Decodable { let temp : Double }

struct Weather : Decodable { let description: String }

struct Wind : Decodable { let speed : Double }

...

do {
   let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherData.self, from: urlContent)
   let description = result.weather.first?.description ?? "unknown"
   let temp = result.main.temp
   let wind = result.wind.speed
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.weatherResult.text = "Current weather is \(description) with a temperature of \(temp) and a wind speed of \(wind) mph."
   }

} catch { print(error) }
```

Notes:

- Don't use `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift, use native types.
- Never cast the result of `JSONSerialization` to `AnyObject`, cast it to the expected type (Array, Dictionary, String or numeric type).
- Never use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. The option (as well as `.mutableLeaves`) is pointless.
- Never `sync` to the main thread. Always do `async.`

Comment: This was extremely helpful information! Thank you very much for replying!